# How can I get a standardized track file (GPX/KML/...) out of a trip recorded with the SafeTrx app?

Tags: gps

The German DGzRS provides the app [SafeTrx](https://www.seenotretter.de/safetrx) which can be used to record tracks while doing water sports. While the app is primarily targeted for assisting search&rescue operations it also stores recorded tracks and allows viewing them later on. I want to download these tracks in some kind of standard format (GPX, KML or anything else that GPSbabel understands will do) to do some more analysis on the recorded tracks. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

In the app go to "Menu->My Profile->Trip History". Select the desired trip, then use the "share"-button in the lower left corner. Copy the Link it generates. The link has the following format:

`https://safetrx.seenotretter.de/sharetrip.html?id=SOME_ID&token=SOME_TOKEN`

Take note of the URL parameters`SOME_ID` and `SOME_TOKEN`, then download the track data e.g. using `wget`:

```bash
wget 'https://safetrx.seenotretter.de/api/admin/trips/share/SOME_ID?token=SOME_TOKEN' -O trip.json
```

This will safe the raw data as `trip.json`.

However this is proprietary file format. It can be converted to a CSV file that GPSbabel can read with the following [jq](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/)-Script:

```
(
  [["utc_d", "utc_t", "lat", "lon", "hdop", "head", "speed"]]
  +
  ([.pings[].tripPoints[] | [
    .dateTime[6:10] + "/" + .dateTime[3:5] + "/" + .dateTime[:2],
    .dateTime[11:19],
    .latitude,
    .longitude,
    .horizontalAccuracy,
    .heading,
    .speed
  ]] | sorted)
)[] | @csv
```

Note that you need the `--raw-output / -r` option so that `jq` won't escape the CSV. To read the result with gpsbabel, use `gpsbabel -t -i unicsv`.

To put it all together in a single a single command, e.g. to get a KML file `trip.kml` you can use:

```bash
wget 'https://safetrx.seenotretter.de/api/admin/trips/share/SOME_ID?token=SOME_TOKEN' -O - \
  | jq -r '([["utc_d", "utc_t", "lat", "lon", "hdop", "head", "speed"]] + ([.pings[].tripPoints[] | [.dateTime[6:10] + "/" + .dateTime[3:5] + "/" + .dateTime[:2], .dateTime[11:19], .latitude, .longitude, .horizontalAccuracy, .heading, .speed]] | sort))[] | @csv' \
  | gpsbabel -t -i unicsv -f - -o kml -F trip.kml
```